# How can I automatically scale a $display column width?

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, test-bench

**Disclaimer**: I answered my own question, which is [explicitly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  I noticed a colleague at work writing code that left the simulation log file difficult to read.  I searched the site for a solution, but found none.

---

I want to `$display` strings in a column like in a fixed-width table.
However, I don't know what the maximum column width of my strings is
ahead of time.

Let's say I have an array of SystemVerilog strings (`names`).
When I `$display` them, I guess at a width for the column (10),
but my guess is too small:

```
module tb;

string names [5];

initial begin
    names = '{
        "ALU"           ,
        "COMPARATOR_3"  ,
        "MEMORY"        ,
        "FLOP"          ,
        "ram_macro_with_a_long_name"
    };

    // Display all elements of the array
    foreach (names[i]) begin
        $display("| %10s |", names[i]);
    end
end

endmodule
```

This is the output:

```
|        ALU |
| COMPARATOR_3 |
|     MEMORY |
|       FLOP |
| ram_macro_with_a_long_name |
```

This is the output I want:

```
|                        ALU |
|                 COMPARATOR |
|                     MEMORY |
|                       FLOP |
| ram_macro_with_a_long_name |
```

I could guess a really big number (like 100), but it might be a lot bigger
than I need.

How can I automatically scale the width of the `$display`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the array to calculate the maximum string length
using the `len` array method.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017,
section 6.16 *String data type*.
Then create the format string using `$sformatf`.

```
module tb;

string names [5];
int maxlen = 0;
string fmt;

initial begin
    names = '{
        "ALU"           ,
        "COMPARATOR"    ,
        "MEMORY"        ,
        "FLOP"          ,
        "ram_macro_with_a_long_name"
    };

    // First, lets calculate the maximum string length
    foreach (names[i]) begin
        if (names[i].len() > maxlen) maxlen = names[i].len();
    end

    // Create the format which will be used by $display
    //      %%  ... double "%" is needed to create a literal "%"
    //      %0d ... this formats the maxlen number
    //      s   ... string format
    //      |   ... this is just the character I chose for the start/end of the field
    fmt = $sformatf("| %%%0ds |", maxlen);

    // Display all elements of the array
    foreach (names[i]) begin
        $display($sformatf(fmt, names[i]));
    end
end

endmodule
```

This is the output:

```
|                        ALU |
|                 COMPARATOR |
|                     MEMORY |
|                       FLOP |
| ram_macro_with_a_long_name |
```

Here is a runnable example on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/BRYr).

---

The output above is right-justified.  To get left-justified output, use:

```
fmt = $sformatf("| %%-%0ds |", maxlen);
```

Output:

```
| ALU                        |
| COMPARATOR                 |
| MEMORY                     |
| FLOP                       |
| ram_macro_with_a_long_name |
```