# Systemverilog string variable as format specifier for $display/$write

Tags: printing, format, system-verilog, display

I'm trying to create a variable format specifier for use in $display/$write. I've tried a large number of things, but here is what I have at the moment.

What I want to end up with is: $display(format_var,data_1,data_2), where the format string is pre-calculated using $sformatf or other.

Code:

```
module test;
function void pprint(input int data_1,input int field_1,input int data_2,input int field_2);
string  format;
begin 
    format = $sformatf("%0d'h%%%0dx,%0d'h%%%0dx",field_1,field_1/4,field_2,field_2/4);
    $display("format = %s",format);
    $display(format,data_1,data_2);
end
endfunction

initial 
begin
    pprint(5,8,73737229,128);
    $stop;
end
endmodule
```

The output I expect is:

```
format = 8'h%2x,128'h%32x
8'h05,128'h000000000000000000000000465240D
```

The output I get is:

```
format = 8'h%2x,128'h%32x
8'h%2x,128'h%32x          5   73737229
```

What do I need to do? The simulator is Vivado 2020.3

Later:

Trying more things, the following function does do what I want. My conclusion is that $display/$write can't take a variable as the format string, but $sformatf can.

```
function void pprint(input int data_1,input int field_1,input int data_2,input int field_2);
string  format;
string  outstr;
begin 
    format = $sformatf("%0d'h%%%0dx,%0d'h%%%0dx",field_1,field_1/4,field_2,field_2/4);
    $display("format = %s",format);
    $display("%s",$sformatf(format,data_1,data_2));
end
endfunction
```

Comment: Try your code on edaplayground on different simulators (like vcs).  See also [How can I automatically scale a $display column width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65691848/how-can-i-automatically-scale-a-display-column-width)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function void pprint(
    input logic [4095:0] data_1,
    input int field_1,
    input logic [4095:0] data_2,
    input int field_2 );
  string  format; 
  format = $sformatf("%0d'h%%%0dh,%0d'h%%%0dh",
    field_1, (field_1+3)/4,
    field_2, (field_2+3)/4 );
  $display("format = %s",format);
  $display($sformatf(format,data_1,data_2));
endfunction
```

This should give you the output:

```
format = 8'h%02h,128'h%032h
8'h05,128'h000000000000000000000000465240D
```

Adding a zero between the `%` and digit could tells the simulator to pad the upper bits with zeros.
For some reason `$display(format,data_1,data_2)` did not use the format on simulators on edaplayground, but it did work with `$sformatf` so I simply nested it.
I needed to increase the bit width of the input data otherwise it would show leading zeros over 8 digits. Adjust if necessary.
Adding 3 to the field is for handling non multiples of 4. It will always round down after division.

Comment: In my case I do want the zero padding. to the nearest byte. I hadn't considered non-multiples of four for my use case but I like the ability to handle it. Thanks!

That $display doesn't work I find interesting and I wonder if it's part of the spec that it doesn't handle a string variable, or it slipped through the cracks.

Answer (score 0):

According to section *21.3.3 Formatting data to a string* of the [SystemVerilog LRM](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/system-verilog/info), only `$sformat` and `$sformatf` have a specific formatting argument that can be a string literal or string variable. All other output tasks like `$display` treat *any* string literal argument as format specifiers and do not interpret the strings inside string variables for formatting.