# How do you escape % in SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

How do you escape `%` in the SystemVerilog `$display` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.2.1 *The display and write tasks*:

> The special character string %% indicates the display of the percent
> sign character %

```
module tb;
    initial $display("hello %% world");
endmodule
```

The above displays:

```
hello % world
```

Run it on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/kCgY).

For a more complex example, see [How can I automatically scale a $display column width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65691848/how-can-i-automatically-scale-a-display-column-width)